# Visual Studio Watch Tool Issue(asm code)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, assembly, 64-bit, watch

I have an issue with Visual Studio 2015. I am following an [x64 Assembly Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=guru397zg2g&list=PL0C5C980A28FEE68D&index=2) series on YouTube, but there is an issue. 
When I use the watch tool to check the value of the EAX register it always displays the value of 3435973836. Here is what my program looks like:
Visual Studio screenshot: "http://prntscr.com/c713mv"

```html
Main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

extern "C" int GetValueFromASM();

int main() {
 
 cout << "ASM said: " << GetValueFromASM() << endl;
 _getch();
 return 0;
}


ASMFunctions.asm
.code
GetValueFromASM proc
 mov eax, 78
 ret
GetValueFromASM endp
end
```

Comment: Did you execute the `mov eax,78`? On the screenshot it looks like the breakpoint is ahead of `mov`. After single instruction step the eax should be 78.  Check rather disassembly window for exact breakpoint position and also maybe there's CPU register window somewhere (I don't have VS, so I'm just guessing). In most of the debuggers the highlighted line is ahead of it's execution, so the highlight shows which instruction will be executed when you hit "step ***" command.

Comment: Yes, it seems that the breakpoint was too early. I feel rather stupid for making such a mistake. Thank you for highlighting that!

Comment: so the problem is solved but im just curious, where does 3435973836 value come from then?does it always have that value before mov eax,78?

Comment: @rcd Looking at it in hex, 3435973836 == 0xCCCCCCCC.  Looks like default values for stack?

Comment: @rcd I found this on another topic:" A quick search shows 3435973836 to be the value Windows gives unassigned memory on x64 - this is telling, as it suggests you have pointers pointing out into nowhere." by Sean McSomething

Comment: interesting to know that 0xcc is int 3. maybe for debugging purposes. oh well

Comment: @rcd `0xCCCCCCCC` is used only as debug marker, in release build the value is undefined (anything what is left there by OS/other process). I found some list of commonly used values (although I bet there must be some official MSDN article somewhere too, I just didn't find it) here: https://www.softwareverify.com/memory-bit-patterns.php

Comment: @Ped7g thanks for the link!